# Where should my water filter drain connect to my sink plumbing?

Tags: drain

I asked the manufacturer where to install the drain and sent them a photo of my setup. After reading a bit more online, I think I got some bad advice. Can you let me know if this needs to be redone?

Where does the RO drain need to be placed? If vertically under the sink between the sink and the trap, I probably need to change all the pipes as there may not be enough room for this saddle. If I need to change the location, do I patch the hole I made or just buy a new piece and swap it out?

[image]

Comment: @gnicko is the concern that gas could escape if the puncture isn't sealed well enough? Otherwise, it appears that some RO runoff will leak left, some right, helping to keep the trap weir filled. (It's probably unusual for the trap arm, especially one that short to be 100% sloped correctly...

Comment: Typically, any drain from a sanitary device requires an air gap. What does the manual say? What's the device make and model?

Comment: You are correct that the saddle should go on the sink's tail piece.  If it doesn't fit then yes you should cut and redo it so it's a couple of inches lower.  It's not hard or expensive.  It looks like you have an AAV up there, hopefully you can reuse that?

Answer (score 1):

The best place would be just under the sink and before the p-trap.

The p-trap is just hand screwed on both ends so it can be remove easily if need be.

You can buy a replacement part for the one you already have hole in it. Again no tools needed it is just hand screwed.

Comment: Adding it upstream of the trap (and that close to the sink drain) would make for quite a bit of noise. Also, an air gap may be required. I'd be consulting the installation manual.